# ошибки joomla 3 "was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet"

Tags: joomla

То ли после переeзда, то ли после обновления джумлы появились ошибки

при входе в админку

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://site.ru/administrator/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://site.ru//administrator/templates,_isis,_css,_template.css,qd6a564e896487c6e6304f783d58db632+language,_ru-RU,_ru-RU.css,qd6a564e896487c6e6304f783d58db632.pagespeed.cc.k7-5lV03Kh.css.html'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: ошибка появилась после добавления модуля pagespeed в apache, после отключения работа нормализуется, но данный модуль нужен, как все же правильно сделать настройку?

Comment: возможно в конфигах у вас указано имя сайта "http://" вместо "https:" поэтому джумла пытается обращаться к ресурсам по нешифрованному протоколу